# Provider not found exception and can't solve it

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have this flutter page, that has got a button that let the user authenticate via google services

```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return TemplateLogReg(
    
    // a lot of code here
        ElevatedButton.icon(
                                 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                 onPrimary: Colors.red,), 
                                 icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
                                 label:Text(""), 
                                 onPressed: () {  
                                 final provider =
Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider(context,listen:false);
                                            provider.googleLogin();
                                          },
                                        ),
```

The class that i use for this task is here:

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async{
    final googleUser =await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if(googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    notifyListeners(); 
  }

}
```

When i try to launch app, i get this error, but i can't solve it, im a newebie in flutter, can u help me?

```
ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GoogleSignInProvider> above this registrationPage Widget
```

Ok i understand that build has to introduce this

```
Widget build (BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
...
)
```

But i have that return TemplateLogReg, so i don't know how to introduce that in my code

Comment: as I said. you can put it on top of your MaterialApp

Comment: can you explain that with an example? Sorry im confuesd about that

Comment: do you need multiple "GoogleSignInProvider"s in your app? or just one is enough?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your top-level widget (e.g. MaterialApp), with ChangeNotifierProvider.

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => new GoogleSignInProvider(),
  child: MaterialApp(...
)
```

Comment: In my example MaterialApp is TemplateLogReg?

Comment: where you are using this widget. wrap it in ChangeNotifierProvider

Comment: if you need only one instance. only wrap your MaterialApp inside the ChangeNotifierProvider as shown in the code sample.